# Set select element option on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I want the page to auto-select some value ('hot', 'new', etc.) depending on the
`$r->category` value which is loaded from database. The `$r->category` value contains some string that could be 'hot', 'new', etc.

Input element:

```
<input type="text" id="cex" value="<?php echo $r->category?>">
```

The select option:

```
<select name="ktgr" onChange="cek();">
    <option id='n' value="normal">normal</option>       
    <option id='h' value="hot">hot</option>     
    <option id='nw' value="new">new</option>        
    <option id='u' value="upcoming">upcoming</option>       
</select>
```

The javascript function

```
function cek()
{
    var j = document.getElementById("cex").value;
    if(j=='normal')
        document.getElementById('n').selected=true;
    else if(j=='hot')
        document.getElementById('h').selected=true;
    else if(j=='new')
        document.getElementById('nw').selected=true;
    else if(j=='upcomming')
        document.getElementById('u').selected=true;             
}
```

Comment: I believe you should run cek function on document load, not on select change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code will set the value of the select element to the initial value every time any option is selected. For example, if `'hot'` is the value from the server, and a user selects `'new'`, the `cek` function will execute in the change event and change the value back to `'hot'`.

Instead, only set the select element's value to the initial value from the server once. A working example is below.

```js
function cek() {
  var j = document.getElementById("cex").value;

  if (j == 'normal')
    document.getElementById('n').selected = true;
  else if (j == 'hot')
    document.getElementById('h').selected = true;
  else if (j == 'new')
    document.getElementById('nw').selected = true;
  else if (j == 'upcoming')
    document.getElementById('u').selected = true;
}
```

```html
<body onload="cek()">
  <input id="cex" value="new" />

  <select name="ktgr">
    <option id='n' value="normal">normal</option>
    <option id='h' value="hot">hot</option>
    <option id='nw' value="new">new</option>
    <option id='u' value="upcoming">upcoming</option>
  </select>
</body>
```